# How to used the firebase appChek with recapatchaV3 (ReCaptchaV3Provider) in react js

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, firebase-app-check

I try to use the firebase's appCheck in my create-react-app with Recaptcha V3 but I have an error which I dont understand :

> err : Uncaught (in promise) Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id

My code in Firebase-config.js :
(I follow the documentation )

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth'
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import {initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider} from "firebase/app-check"

const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
 authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
 databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATA_BASE_URL,
 projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
 storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
 messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSENGER_SENDER_ID,
 appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
 measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASURMENT_ID
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
 provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(process.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY),
 isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
})
const db = getDatabase(app)
const auth = getAuth(app)
export {db, appCheck, auth}
```

I searched this error on many blog but I dont find a solution
Thank you in advance